# Windows Phone: How to Sign an App

Tags: windows-phone-7, certificate

Once I have built an app for Windows Phone, how do I get a certificate and how do I sign it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you mean signing for distribution on the Marketplace, you don't. When you submit your application for certification it will have a number of tests run on it, your authorisation requirements will be added automatically and the final package will be signed before being made available.

Comment: Additionally, IF an app is ever found to be malicious, Microsoft can not only pull the app from Marketplace, but can revoke the certificate.  Once the certificate is revoked, the app will automatically uninstall from all phones.  No user action required.  That's a big boost for security on the platform.

Answer (score 4):

You don't. [Submit](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/home/about/app_submission_walkthrough) it to AppHub for review. If it is accepted MS will sign it and place it in the marketplace for download.